# Harry Potter fanfic about Voldemort's Hogwarts years

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, voldemort, fan-fiction

Please help to identify a fanfic, a chapter of which I read on someone's blog.

It is about Voldemort's school years.
Narrator: Lestrange
Main characters: Voldemort (mostly as Tom Riddle), Lestrange, Avery, Bellatrix  Black (later Lestrange)

The chapter described how Tom Riddle nearly died creating the first(?) Horcrux (diary).

It is hinted that Voldemort was sexually related with Lestrange, also Bellatrix and some other people of both sexes. But sex was just another means to control people for him.

The text was in English. The author (or authors) is supposedly Russian, but there was no name mentioned, only some nickname.

Comment: Can you remember the nickname of the author? It might help with identifying the story.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot No, it was a long time ago, and the nickname was not necessarily the author's but that of the blog owner.

Comment: The post itself was reposted several times, making it somewhat difficult to trace the original poster.

Comment: I really can't imagine Voldemort having any interest in sex.  (I know, I know.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston that was exactly the point - V was obsessed with controlling others, and sex was just another method of control